# Pandas: Inconsistency in converting from datetime.datetime object to Index / DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of dictionarys both contain `[{datetime.datetime: int}...]`. I use `pd.Series(list_of_dict)` to convert it to a series object. However, for one list it converts it to a `pd.series` with `Index` type index. Another is `DatetimeIndex` index. What could reasons be for this inconsistency?

I want a `DatetimeIndex` index btw:P Many thanks!

A sample: `ss=pd.Series(d)` `s=pd.Series(datetime_counter)`

```
In [120]: list(d.keys())[0]
Out[123]: datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 9, 3, 47, 57)

In [124]: list(datetime_counter.keys())[0]
Out[132]: datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 7, 7, 35, 38)

In [133]: ss.index
Out[136]:
DatetimeIndex(['2018-11-09 03:47:57', '2018-11-09 09:12:19',
               '2018-11-09 09:02:42', '2018-11-09 09:02:37',
               '2018-11-09 09:02:23', '2018-11-09 09:00:42',
               '2018-11-09 08:38:37', '2018-11-09 06:50:53',
               '2018-11-08 10:24:49', '2018-11-08 10:31:28',
               ...
               '2017-09-25 12:27:12', '2017-09-25 12:19:55',
               '2017-09-25 11:34:57', '2017-09-25 11:31:55',
               '2017-09-25 11:24:56', '2017-09-25 11:23:58',
               '2017-09-25 11:08:29', '2017-09-25 11:02:00',
               '2017-09-26 00:24:13', '2017-09-26 06:51:14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=56639, freq=None)

In [137]: s.index
Out[137]:
Index([2018-11-07 07:35:38, 2018-11-05 17:52:32, 2018-11-06 20:37:20,
       2018-11-06 14:19:13, 2018-11-06 09:50:49, 2018-11-06 09:32:45,
       2018-11-05 18:43:29, 2018-11-05 18:27:14, 2018-11-05 18:00:52,
       2018-11-05 17:57:05,
       ...
       2011-03-16 10:35:50, 2011-03-15 21:52:00, 2017-10-31 23:03:20,
       2017-10-20 10:00:11, 2017-10-18 20:35:47, 2017-10-19 22:16:08,
       2017-10-19 15:40:42, 2017-10-19 09:33:22, 2017-10-19 07:12:23,
       2017-10-18 22:53:12],
      dtype='object', length=83539)

In [138]:
```

Comment: I have run into similar situations in the past, thats why now I always use `s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)` every time I create one to ensure I have `DatetimeIndex` and not `Index`. Don't know the reason though.

Comment: I used `astype` :D tks for your comment!